# `:zlib.gunzip` and `:zlib.inflate/2` work fine, but I get `:data_error` when trying to make a stream using `:zlib.safeInflate/2``

Tags: elixir

Made a file using `cat file.txt | gzip > file.gz`. The rest works if this file is tiny (< 1kb or so), but any bigger and my issue pops up. I wish to process very large files and would thus like to make it a stream to not hold the whole thing in memory.

```
filename = "file.gz"
{:ok, fd} = File.open(filename)
compressed_data = IO.binread(fd, :all)
```

#### This works fine:

```
IO.inspect(compressed_data |> :zlib.gunzip)
```

and so does

```
z = :zlib.open()
:zlib.inflateInit(z, 16 + 15)
result = try do
  result = :zlib.inflate(z, compressed_data)
  :zlib.inflateEnd(z)
  result
after
  :zlib.close(z)
end
IO.inspect(result)
```

## Stream attempt that fails with `:data_error`

```
defmodule Z do
  def inflate(compressed_stream) do
    Stream.transform(
      compressed_stream,
      fn ->
        z = :zlib.open()
        :zlib.inflateInit(z, 16 + 15)
        z
      end,
      fn chunk, z ->
        enum =
          Stream.resource(
            fn -> (:zlib.safeInflate(z, chunk)) end,
            fn
              :halt -> {:halt, nil}
              {:continue, decompressed} -> {List.wrap(decompressed), :zlib.safeInflate(z, [])}
              {:finished, decompressed} -> {List.wrap(decompressed), :halt}
            end,
            & &1
          )
        {enum, z}
      end,
      fn z ->
        :zlib.inflateEnd(z)
        :zlib.close(z)
      end
    )
  end
end

IO.inspect(
  filename
  |> File.stream!
  |> Z.inflate
  |> Enum.into("")
)
```

I get a `:data_error` at the `inflateEnd` call. If I comment it, I get it later anyway.

Comment: This was solved thanks to asummers (on the elixir discord). My problem was caused by the File.stream! call defaulting to line mode. One fix is to use `|> File.stream!([], 1024)`. Another is to not do this at all and just use gz built-in support with `File.stream!([:compressed, :read])` instead.

Comment: It is completely valid to post an actual answer to your own question